# Magento Add to Cart Button, Onepage checkout works only after refresh browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I have this problem for several weeks. When someone visits the shop (for the first time but randomly too) he cannot add to cart, from the product page button until he refreshes his browser. Something similar happens in the Onepage Checkout.

on the product page I get this error from the firebug console:

> TypeError: productAddToCartForm is undefined

I have already searched the web for a solution, with no luck.

Any help will be apreciated

Comment: If you check your page source, you can see jQuery is included twice. This may cause error when adding products into cart.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have removed the lightbox jquery but still the same problem. After cleaning browser cache on first load...

Comment: Now the shop is working fine for me, I have seen several issues before you removed the additional jQuery files.

Comment: Also try to resolve the issue that you can see in the console.

Comment: the counter issue from the console has been resolved as well as the jquery conflict. The button still doesn't work when you enter for the first time...

Comment: Also when you are at onepage checkout when trying to login clicking the button I get this in the console `TypeError: loginForm is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

This is related to jQuery conflict.

If you check your page source, you can see two version of jQuery is included.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bagatzounis.com/web/js/lightboxes/jQuery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try to remove the one which is not needed, it will fix the issue.

This is something you need to do with the template.